# Extracting data from PDF tables with multi-line rows: tabula

Tags: conversion, pdf

I am trying to convert large tables in PDF form to CSVs. I was wondering if there are recommendations for how to extract tables in which rows span multiple lines as in the tabula example [here](https://github.com/tabulapdf/tabula-extractor/issues/23)? My own data are somewhat simpler in that there are no subheaders, but the same issue arises - rows spanning multiple lines. Thank you in advance for your suggestions! This is what I've tried on the example given above:

```
library("tabulizer")

# specify filename
file <- '~/Desktop/atipp_coordinators_govt_agencies.pdf'

# read file
out1 <- extract_tables(file, output = "data.frame",
method = 'lattice', pages=2)
```

Unfortunately, the multi-line row is read into separate rows.

Comment: This question belongs on [SU]. But you'd better explain tabula in your post.